# ObjectDataSource 'ObjectDataSource1' could not find a non-generic method 'UpdateProdus' that has parameters:

Tags: objectdatasource

ASPX Code:

```
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="pId" HeaderText="pId" SortExpression="pId" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="pName" HeaderText="pName" SortExpression="pName" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="pUnitateMasura" HeaderText="pUnitateMasura" SortExpression="pUnitateMasura" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="pPret" HeaderText="pPret" SortExpression="pPret" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="pStocInitial" HeaderText="pStocInitial" SortExpression="pStocInitial" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="pIntrariMarfa" HeaderText="pIntrariMarfa" SortExpression="pIntrariMarfa" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="pStocRamas" HeaderText="pStocRamas" SortExpression="pStocRamas" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="pCantitateVanduta" HeaderText="pCantitateVanduta" SortExpression="pCantitateVanduta" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="pValoareVanduta" HeaderText="pValoareVanduta" SortExpression="pValoareVanduta" />
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" DeleteMethod="DeleteProdus" SelectMethod="GetAllProduse" TypeName="ProduseDataAccesLayer" UpdateMethod="UpdateProdus">
                        <DeleteParameters>
                            <asp:Parameter Name="pId" Type="Int32" />
                        </DeleteParameters>
                        <SelectParameters>
                            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="LabelUserIdentity"              Name="NumeUser" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
                        </SelectParameters>
                        <UpdateParameters>
                            <asp:Parameter Name="pId" Type="Int32" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="pName" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="pUnitateMasura" Type="Double" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="pPret" Type="Double" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="pStocInitial" Type="Double" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="pIntrariMarfa" Type="Double" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="pStocRamas" Type="Double" />
                        </UpdateParameters>
                    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

my method:

public static void UpdateProdus(int pId, string pName, double pUnitateMasura, double pPret, double pStocInitial, double pIntrariMarfa, double pStocRamas)
    {
        using (MySqlConnection myCon = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["amstoc"].ConnectionString))
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("sp_UpdateProdus", myCon);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

```
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("iProdus", pId);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("prodNume", pName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("prodUnitateMasura", pUnitateMasura);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("prodPret", pPret);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("prodStocInitial", pStocInitial);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("prodIntrariMarfa", pIntrariMarfa);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("prodStocRamas", pStocRamas);

        myCon.Open();

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    } 
}
```

my stored Procerure:

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_UpdateProdus`(in iProdus int, in prodNume nvarchar(120), in prodUnitateMasura double, in prodPret double, in prodStocInitial double, in prodIntrariMarfa double, in prodStocRamas double)
BEGIN

```
update tblproduse set tblproduse.ProdusNume = prodNume, tblproduse.ProdusUnitateMasura = prodUnitateMasura, tblproduse.ProdusPret = prodPret, tblproduse.ProdusStocInitial = prodStocInitial, tblproduse.ProdusIntrariMarfa = prodIntrariMarfa, tblproduse.ProdusStocRamas = prodStocRamas where tblproduse.ProdusId = iProdus;
```

END